# Load GWT webapp into a DIV like an iframe (jQuery .load())

Tags: jquery, ajax, gwt, xmlhttprequest

Currently I have an iframe to wrap my GWT apps, but I experiencing some slowness and I think it is because the iframe. I'm trying to load the content through a XMLHttpRequest with the .load() jQuery function, into a div, but does not work.

It downloads all the source code correctly, but does not displays it into the div :/

I've tried with JSP tests with just a body and some text, and it works, so I suppose there is a kind of problem when it's a GWT webapp.

This is my code:

```
$("#mainFrame").load(url, function(response){$("#mainFrame").html(response)});
```

(Yes, I know I'm not supposed to do the function with the html() call but it does not work without that. I don't know why)

BTW, both are in the same server; currently in localhost. So I've discard cross-domain issues.

Answer (score 0):

GWT apps, when using the built-in linkers, listen to the `onload` and `DOMContentLoad` events, so the *.nocache.js script **has** to be loaded before (i.e. synchronously from within your HTML host page).

You can write a custom linker to overcome this limitation, but you'll need a somewhat deep knowledge of GWT applications' bootstrap process, so if I were you I'd rather start with proving that the iframe is the issue.

Comment: Loaded before what onload event? Tha main page onload? I can't do that, it has to be able to load the div content whenever, even after onload event. It is like a webapp selector menu on the left and on the right the iframe-like div that loads the selected webapps into self.